# Binary Search Generics for an Array using Java

Tags: java, generics

Can someone point out what's wrong with this code? I had to shove in a recursion into a binary search, and the assignment specified a signature with

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>>       
     int binarySearch(AnyType[] a, AnyType x);
```

Here's my code...

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>>   
int binarySearch(AnyType[] a, AnyType x){

    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;

    while(low <= high){

    int mid = (low + high) / 2; 

    if(a[mid].compareTo(x) < 0) {
        AnyType[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid + 1, a.length);
        return binarySearch(b, x);
    } else if(a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0) {
        high = mid - 1;
        AnyType[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid - 1);
        return binarySearch(b, x);
    } else {
        return mid;
    }
}
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a secondary method that does not copy the original array; but instead takes the indices of the search.

Like binarySubSearch(a, x, start, end).  I'd give you more but I think this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors you need to add the mid point to the returned index and the second range copy was incorrect.

```
  if(a[mid].compareTo(x) < 0) {
    AnyType[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid + 1, a.length);
    int index = binarySearch(b, x);
    if(index != -1){
      index = mid +1 + index;
    }
    return index;
  } else if(a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0) {
    AnyType[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);  <=== not mid -1
    return binarySearch(b, x);
  } else {
    return mid;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need to ask... what does this line mean "return index==-1?index:mid +1 + index;" ?